# Computing an area with geometric methods

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Consider the construction below (it is self-evident, no tricks or misleading drawing)
[image]

**What is the area enclosed by the curve that goes through the points H,J,M,L ?**

I solved the problem using integration after rotating everything by $\pi/4$ and scaling length by a factor $\sqrt{2}$:
here's what I did
[image]

After scaling back areas by a factor $\frac{1}{2}$, the area is $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\sqrt{7}/4}^{\sqrt{7}/4} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}-\sqrt{2-x^2}+1 dx=\frac{1}{8} \left( \sqrt{7}-8sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{2}})+2tan^{-1}(\sqrt{7}) \right) \simeq 0.146$$

**Now, is there a proof that would not resort to a heavy use of calculus ?**

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but please clarify: Which region do you exactly refer to in 'area enclosed by the curve that goes through the points H,J,M,L'?

Comment: The part inside the small circle and outside the large circle.

Comment: The [formula for the area of a circular segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area) should come in handy. Compute the area of $HJML$ as a segment of the smaller circle, and then subtract the area of the of the thinner segment (between $L$ and $M$) of the larger circle. The tricky part is computing the central angles involved.

Comment: @RossMilikan precisely !

Comment: The angles are no problem. We can coordinatize, and compute. That will give us explicit expressions for trigonometric functions of the angles.

Comment: In case you are trying to look this up, it may be helpful to know that the figure in question is called a *lune*. [The MathWorld page about it](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lune.html) may be of some use.